# DigiKeyboard - type a backslash (\)

Tags: digispark

I'm using digiKeyboard library to type to a powershell, but I need to type a backslash (a lot of them), but I can't figure it out.

I have been looking for the solution for about 3 hours and I still can't find it.
Please let me know how to make a backslash work.

The powershell command that I want to execute:

`cmd /C "start /MIN powershell iwr -Uri https://tinyurl.com/WjnAU6 -OutFile c:\windows\temp\b.jpg;sp 'HKCU:Control Panel\Desktop' WallPaper 'c:\windows\temp\b.jpg';$a=1;do{RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True;sleep 1}while($a++-le59)"`

It just changes the wallpaper with a downloaded image, try in on your friend.

Comment: this is what you are missing? it prints one backslash: `print("\\")`

Comment: You don't need a backslash. You can use forward slash for path separation in any version of Windows from Vista onwards (maybe even earlier).

Comment: @Juraj this somehow worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include `\` in a string so it can be printed you have to escape it.  `\` is itself the escape character, so doubling it up "escapes the escape character" so it is interpreted as a normal character.

So to print `"c:\windows"` you would actually have to type `"c:\\windows"` and the `\\` gets changed by the compiler into just `\`